# Excel error: Geting external data from microsoft query

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2010

I am fairly familiar with retrieving data from SQL Servers into Excel 2010.  Recently I read the following article on allowing users to submit parameters to a stored procedure and was trying it out:

[Data from SQL server](http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-data-from-sql-server-stored.html)

I am able to walk though all the steps of connecting to the server using the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 driver.  I can call the stored procedure and return data in the Microsoft Query window (through step 8 of the instructions in the above link).

I can move through all 14 steps with ease.  However, after linking the parameters to specific cells and defining the location for the data, hitting "OK" to return the data to the spreadsheet I receive the following error:

[image]

Some searching suggested that it may be a permission issue with the Stored Proc so I tried several variations of `GRANT EXEC ON [dbo].[uspGLDetail_ItemNumber] TO PUBLIC`.  The proc I am attempting to execute is `[uspGLDetail_ItemNumber]`.

[image]

You can see I am returning data in the Microsoft Query window:

[image]

I am not sure why the error is referencing that specific object.  I attempted to check the permissions on the listed object, but do not find that procedure on our Server. Perhaps, part of the solution could be how to find the listed object in the error.

I am thinking this is perhaps more of an issues with Excel communicating to the server than a permission issue on the stored proc so was trying a few different drivers with no luck.  However, I have successfully been retrieving data into excel From SQL Server with no issue for a long time.

Comment: Posting a link to an article you read won't show us what you're doing wrong. Also, you've jumped to the assumption that the error message is wrong just because you can't figure out how to solve the problem. It clearly says you don't have EXECUTE permission. How do you know that you have the rights to GRANT EXEC? And where do you see `[dbo].[uspGLDetail_ItemNumber]` anywhere in that error message?

Comment: As the title suggests I am looking for help on addressing the error message in excel.  I do have rights to GRANT EXEC and have been doing so for quite some time successfully on other procs.  The only thing different in this scenario is I am trying to pull data using "From Microsoft Query." in stead of "From SQL Server."  I can in fact retrieve the same data using "From SQL Server."  The reason I am attempting "From Microsoft Query" is to allow Excel users an easy way to pass parameters to the procedure without having to go into the data connection properties each time.

Comment: Typically you would use a View for this, not a stored procedure. Check with your DBA. You (public user) only needs Select permission.

Comment: @rheitzman - Thanks for the information.  I will see what I can find on using a View to accomplish this.  I am not entirely sure how that would work.  Are you passing a variable to the view from excel in that case?